# Sort & Uniq the values on specific column

Tags: bash, awk

I am having a data separated by : delimeted

```
AA:w_c;w_c;r_c:1;3
BB:sync;sync:4
CC:t_wak;t_wak:6;7;8
```

I need to print only one value in column 2 that to unique value. If there are more than one unique value then it need to print in another file.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sort -u -t : -k2,2 file >> txt
awk -F: '{gsub(";"," ",$3)}1' txt
Output:
BB:sync;sync:4
CC t_wak;t_wak 6 7 8
AA w_c;w_c;r_c 1 3
```

Actually I am trying to to do sort and uniq the values in column 2 and copying that output to another file called "txt". Then I am using AWk to replace the ; with space in column 3 seems above code is not working.

Desired Output 1:

```
BB:sync:4
CC:t_wak:6 7 8
```

The above two values are the actual output we need to get to print because in column 2 it contains only one value.

The below one needs to print in another file because in column 2 it contains more than one value.

Desired output 2:

```
AA:w_c;r_c:1;3  
w_c
r_c
```

In column 2 it should have only one value, if there are more than one then need to print in another file by stating them as shown above.

Comment: First of all Thank you for adding your efforts in form code in your question. Could you please provide more clear input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my input is colon delimeted file where in column 2 it needs to have only one value instead 2 or more ..so that's why I am using sort and uniq to remove duplicates and print only one.  Basically in my input in column 2 will having only duplicates values..in rare cases we will see non duplicates with two or more.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 so if the values are non duplicates then should not print in the same file were I am printing the unique values. It should go into another file.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Please let me know still if you face any confusion in the Actual/Desired output.

Comment: @Kent 95% of the cases they will be duplicated but very rarely they are some non duplicated values separated by ; separated values in column 2.. like clo1:a;a:col3:cl4          col1:a;b:clo3:col4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quick solution should work for the example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} 
{ 
    split($2, a, ";")
    v=""; delete u
    for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
    if( ++u[a[i]]<2)
        v=v (i==1?"":";") a[i]
    }
    $2=v
    if(length(u)>1){
        print > "output2.txt"
        next
    }
}7' input
```

Let's do a test:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} 
{ 
        split($2, a, ";")
    v=""; delete u
        for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
        if( ++u[a[i]]<2)
            v=v (i==1?"":";") a[i]
        }
    $2=v
    if(length(u)>1){
        print > "output2.txt"
        next
    }
}7' f
BB:sync:4
CC:t_wak:6;7;8

kent$  cat output2.txt 
AA:w_c;r_c:1;3
```

### If you want to have each value in col2 in the output2.txt:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":";out2="output2.txt"} 
{ 
    split($2, a, ";")
    v=""; delete u
    for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
        if( ++u[a[i]]<2)
            v=v (i==1?"":";") a[i]
        }
    $2=v
    if(length(u)>1){
        print > out2
        for(x in u)
            print x > out2
        next
    }
}7' input
```

Then you'll get:

```
kent$  cat output2.txt
AA:w_c;r_c:1;3
w_c
r_c
```

Comment: Kent, may I know the use of 7 here "}7' input"

Comment: `7` non-zero number does default action in awk. the default action is: print current record(line). @Akhil. which part you have problem to understand? you can add `print xxxx` in codes to output result, it may help you to understand it better.